# Drop down/off/into

Tags: verbs

The verb "drop" itself means letting something fall on the ground, so, let's suppose I have my phone on my hands, I'm holding it, and suddenly someone crashes into me and my cellphone falls off my hand on the ground, should it be: I dropped my cellphone down, or I dropped my cellphone off my hands on the ground?

Another question related to the same verb: There is a brick laying on a wall, a tall wall, and I turned around and my arms hit the brick making it fall, what would I say? I turned around and my arms dropped the brick down? or I turned around and my arms dropped the trick off the wall.?

Here is an example with image:

[image]

If you could also give me some more tips about using the verb *drop*, I'd be thankful :)

Please, forgive me for my horrible, bad-done and shameful pic that I made by myself

Comment: On the first, you don't need anything - you dropped your phone. You'd only need to use down/to/into if you were talking about where the phone went - for example, "I dropped my phone down a well" or "I dropped my phone into the lake". On the brick example, unless you were holding the brick beforehand, you wouldn't say that you dropped it. You could say "The brick dropped to the ground" but if you were trying to convey that you inadvertently pushed it down, you would use a different verb, like "knocked" - "I turned around and knocked the brick off the wall"

Comment: Hum, thank you. I had forgotten that I could've used the verb "knock" too. Anyway "The brick dropped to the ground", is "to" the proper preposition for that sentence? Shouldn't it have been: _The brick dropped onto the ground?_

Comment: The natural way to say it is "the brick dropped *to* the ground".  *Onto* sounds strange, because it emphasizes being on a surface, but what we're really concerned about here is the motion of the brick towards the ground.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't ordinarily use bare *down* with transitive *drop*: the sense of "downness" is more or less built in to the notion of dropping, so ordinarily we use *down* only with an oblique (e.g. *I dropped my phone down the manhole*).

As a complement of *drop*, *off OBL* ordinarily indicates that *OBL* is a surface on which the dropped *OBJ* is lying; we say "I dropped my phone ***from*** or ***out of*** my hand", and *Off* will usually be found only with ***in***transitive *drop*: "The brick dropped from the wall to the street beneath".

Transitive *drop OBJ*, as your initial definition suggests, does not mean "**cause** OBJ to fall"; it means "**allow** OBJ to fall", typically by releasing an *OBJ* you are holding or sustaining in an elevated position. Consequently we would not say that "My arm dropped the brick" in the circumstances you describe; instead we would use a causative verb, one which signifies imparting motion. With an inadvertent action, the most common verb is probably *knock*:

> My arm knocked the brick off the wall.

This can also be used of deliberate actions if *knock* has the sense "deliver a sharp blow":

> I knocked the brick off the wall with a long stick.

Comment: Hum, got it. Thank you for your explaination, but I still have one question, as you said it is an intransitive verb which doesn't need a completement, "drop" itself says someone went down from an elevated place. However, talking about the verb _knock_ then could I say: I knocked the brick off the wall into the lake? It is understood that there is a wall separing a solid area from a lake, or: I knocked the brick from the wall into the lake?

Comment: @DavydDiniz Fersher, that's fine. "From" there is a tad literary: "off" or "off of" would be more usual.

Comment: Hum, I always thought "off" were a replacement of "of" and "from", like, "off" is the junction of these two words, which means: "of" = the description of the place, "from" = the local where it dropped from

Comment: @DavydDiniz "Off" does originally share an origin with "of" - the two were one word in Old English - but it's not related to "from" although in some situations you could use either "off" or "from". In the last 800 years the meanings of "of" and "off" have drifted pretty far apart.

Comment: I got it. So, "off" would be more suitable for that sentence? I knocked the brick off the wall into the lake?

Answer (score 3):

> I'm holding it, and suddenly someone crashes into me and my cellphone falls off my hand

If this is the case, some would suggest you didn't really drop it, it was *knocked out of* your hands.

But you can legitimately say that it dropped, though that was not the root cause of the cellphone mishap. I would suggest

> I dropped it on the ground, where it broke.

You don't have to specify that it was in your hand. That is over-explanatory. Most people would assume you were holding it in your hand anyway. If it fell out of your pocket, then that is a different issue. Only if you were holding it in an unusual way, say between your shoulder and your ear, would you specify the place it dropped from. In which case you would say something like

> I was using my shoulder to hold the phone to my ear and it's not surprising that I dropped it on the ground.

Comment: I got it, but if I said: _I dropped it on the ground_ it might sound that I was sitting on the ground and dropped it not specifically onto the ground, but I dropped it as I was sat, but again, it would be over-explanatory. However, I dropped it onto the ground would sound more fluent?

Comment: You don't have to worry about that. What I suggested is the most natural way to impart that idea.

Comment: Hum, I got it, it's the most spoken way, right? However, "onto" in that sentence would sound more fluent, and grammarly correct, right?

Comment: It would sound fussier and perhaps even over-particular. Most people in casual conversation would use *on*. You want to speak like a native right? One of the mistakes non-native speakers often make is to try to sound too precise.

Comment: "if I said: *I dropped it on the ground* it might sound that I was sitting on the ground and dropped it"  No, no native speaker would interpret it that way.  *You dropped it* and the way in which you dropped it was *on the ground*.  What you're thinking of would have to be phrased like: *"I, sitting on the ground, dropped it"* or maybe *"I dropped it while sitting on the ground."*

Answer (score 1):

David.  I will answer in the order you asked.

1. *I dropped my cellphone down.*
2. *I dropped my cellphone off my hands on the ground?*

It depends on how much information you want to give. #1 gives minimal information, and it could be improved by leaving off "down".  The word adds nothing that "dropped" itself did not already state.  If you were on a spaceship with no gravity a direction might be useful, but on Earth, not so much.

Sentence #2 sounds very awkward. I know what you mean, though. A better way to say it is, "My cellphone dropped out of my hands and onto the ground."

In general, "drop down" and "dropped down" are used informally. Native speakers will use the phrases, but the word "down" is almost always unnecessary. Sometimes we say "fall down" or "fell down". In this case, the "down" is useful, distinguishing the meaning from "fall over".  (**Fall over** describes the situation of something already resting on something, such as the ground, and it tips over sideways.)  That said, we often leave off both "down" and "over", because not every detail need be described.  "The glass fell and broke." Whether it fell over or fell down may well be insignificant compared to it breaking.

To describe the situation with your brick, the word "drop" is incorrect.  You can only drop something you are holding.  (There are special cases.  If you are hunting and bring down a flying duck with your bow, you could state that you "dropped that duck".) So the situation you describe and illustrate:

- I turned around and accidentally hit the brick with my arm. It fell off the wall and broke.